# Ошибка отправки данных с формы на почту php

Tags: php

На сайте данные с формы не отправляются на почту, в чем может быть ошибка?

```html
<form name="sentMessage" action="mail.php" method="POST" id="contactForm" novalidate="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя *" id="name" name="user_name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Укажите пожалуйста ваше имя.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон *" id="email" name="user_phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Укажите пожалуйста ваш номер телефона.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" id="message" name="user_message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Напишите пожалуйста ваше сообщение"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Готово</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$message = $_POST['user_message'];


$mail->isSMTP();                                   
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = 'fromPochta@mail.ru'; 
$mail->Password = 'password'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('fromPochta@mail.ru'); 
$mail->addAddress('toPochta@yandex.ru');     
$mail->isHTML(true);                                

$mail->Subject = 'Message';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' number:' .$phone. '<br>Message:: ' .$message;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: allisworking.html');
}
?>
```

Выдает Error и письмо не приходит, кто то знает, как исправить?

Comment: Т.е. посмотреть исходник и найти `See the ErrorInfo property for details of the error` вам религия не позволяет?

Comment: Можно конкретнее,  как это сделать?

Comment: ```echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;```